# IndexError: Python list index out of range

Tags: list, python-3.5

I have an empty list, (`r`) and declared first element as `r[0] = a`

```
import time, urllib.request,random

def getDictionary():
    word_site = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(word_site)
    txt = response.read()
    return txt.splitlines()

def getWordsList(listOfWords, sample):
    word = ""
    randWords = []
    for i in range(0,sample):
        while(len(word) <=2):
            word = random.choice(listOfWords).decode('utf-8')
        randWords.append(word)
        word = ""
    return randWords
start = True
noOfWords = 25

words = getDictionary()
wordsList = getWordsList(words, noOfWords)

start = True

print ("\nINSTRUCTIONS\nWhen the coundown gets to zero, type the word in lowercase letters!\n That's the only rule!")
name = input("What is your name? ")
name = name.split(" ")
input("Press enter when ready...")

while start == True:

    print("Game will start in: ")
    print ("3 seconds")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("2 seconds")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("1 seconds")
    time.sleep(1)

    times = []
    k = list()
    r = list()
    for i in range(25):
        startTime = time.time()
        userWord = input(str(i+1) + ". " + wordsList[i].capitalize() + " " )
        k.append(wordsList[i].capitalize())
        if (userWord.lower() == wordsList[i].lower()):
            endTime = time.time()
            times.append(endTime - startTime)
            r[i] = str(endTime - startTime)           
        else:
            times.append("Wrong Word")
            r[i] = ("Wrong Word")
```

Above is where I am having a problem.

```
for i in range(25):
    startTime = time.time()
    print (str(i+1) + ". " + str(k[i]) + ": " + str(times[i]) )
a = 0
for i in range(25):
    a = a+i
for i in range(25):
    if r[i] == "Wrong Word":
        r = r.pop(i)
b = (a/len(r))
c = round(b, 2)
print (c)
start = False
```

here is my error:

```
r[i] = "Wrong Word"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pop()` method removes an element from the list and returnes it (see [an example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_pop.htm)). What I think is happening is that at some point the condition of the `if` statment resolves to `true`. Next, after calling `r.pop(i)`  `r` is replaced by its `i`-th element. It's probpably a string so calling its `(i+1)`-th element later can result in `Index out of range` error.

In other words, something like this is happening:

```
r = ["a", "foo", "bar", "baz"]
for i in range(4):
    if r[i] == "a": # for i=0 this gives "a" == "a" 
        r = r.pop(i) # later,this results in r = "a"
```

next loop iteration with `i = 1` will result in `"a"[1]` which will result in `Index out of range`.

---

All in all instead of:

```
for i in range(25):
if r[i] == "Wrong Word":
    r = r.pop(i)
```

you could just write:

```
r = [item for item in r if item != "Wrong word"]
```

which would be also more pythonic solution.